# Android LVL won't Import into Eclipse

Tags: android, android-library, android-lvl

I'm trying to get the Android LVL (App Licensing) setup to work with my software... and I cannot get it to import into Eclipse at all. The documentation says, "add the library folder to your workspace"... but it won't let me. I have rev. 2 downloaded... but when I try to import the project (from /android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/play_licensing/library) it shows up greyed-out in the projects list and won't import. Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag the sources into your project. The intention of the LVL is that you build your own sources and make changes (to try to thwart people that modify your binary by looking for LVL-specific bits).

Comment: I did this and have it working, I think. Even though the primary email on my phone is the 'test' account, it's still telling me to purchase from the market...